# PHP show float number in string

Tags: php, integer

I want to show a **float** number in php string.

something like:

```
My float number is: 0.00003485
```

But when I am using echo I see it like this:

```
My float number is: 3.485E-5
```

Also, I know I can use `printf("%.10f",$float)` code, but I need to use it in lots of places in my string, So I can't use `printf`.

What code should I use on a string, to show floats as they are? I don't want that shorted number (3.485E-5).

Comment: Please explain why you can't use printf(), it's not clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write a function to handle this in any way you want. Why not?

```
function fval($f, $precision = 9) { 
    return number_format($f, $precision); 
}
```

Then any place you need to format, call it out:

```
$f = 3.485E-5;
echo fval($f);  // this will print: 0.000003485
```

Answer (score 0):

At some condition i am prefer declaration float number as string:

MyFloatNumber = "0.0000000000000000000000003485";

so,

echo MyFlatNumber;
//0.0000000000000000000000003485

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can use `printf("%.10f",$float)` code, but I need to use it in lots of places in my string, So I can't use printf.

I have to respectfully disagree with that:

```
printf('My float number is: %1$.8f (again: %1$.8f; once more: %1$.8f)', 0.00003485);
```

Or, if you need it in a string:

```
$foo = sprintf('My float number is: %1$.8f (again: %1$.8f; once more: %1$.8f)', 0.00003485);
```

Of course, if you mean it's against project style guidelines or company policy, that's another story.

> What code should I use on a string, to show floats as they are?

Really? Floats in PHP are a 64-bit [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision format bitmap. According to this [online converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html), number `0.00003485` would be:

```
0010010001010111110011100001110100101110111001001111
```

Of course, they aren't actual ones and zeroes but different voltage levels ;-)